# can't connect to my zookeeper(3.4.12) on windows 10

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I start my local zookeeper service at 2181 port, When I try to use the zkCli.cmd to connect my local service,I always get a message on the server console as follows:
[image]

and this is my dos command which use to connect the zookeeper server:
zkCli.cmd -server 127.0.0.1 2181

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solve. It is my fault for using the command in a wrong way.
just change the 127.0.0.1 2181 to 127.0.0.1:2181.